# Multiple subcharts with differents .Values properties

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to create a chart with multiple subcharts ( 2 instances of ibm-db2oltp-dev). Is there a way to define in the same values.yaml file, different configuration for each instance?

I need two databases:

```
db2inst.instname: user1
db2inst.password: password1
options.databaseName: dbname1

db2inst.instname: user2
db2inst.password: password2
options.databaseName: dbname2
```

I saw it could be done via alias but I didn't find an example explaining how to do it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

In **Chart.yaml** for Helm 3 or in **requirements.yaml** for Helm 2:

```
dependencies:
  - name: ibm-db2oltp-dev                *(full chart name here)*
    repository: http://localhost:10191   *(Actual repository url here)*
    version: 0.1.0                       *(Required version)*
    alias: db1inst                       *(The name of the chart locally)*
  - name: ibm-db2oltp-dev
    repository: http://localhost:10191
    version: 0.1.0
    alias: db2inst
```

[**parentChart/values.yaml:**](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md#overriding-values-of-a-child-chart)

```
someParentChartValueX: x
someParentChartValueY: y

db1inst:
  instname: user1
  db2inst: password1

db2inst:
  instname: user2
  db2inst: password2
```

Comment: In Helm3 its `Chart.yaml` instead of `requirements.yaml`

Comment: Is this actually working? Because as the other answer mentions there are dozens of bug reports that say that this doesn't work at all or doesn't work reliably in Helm 3.

Comment: this will work with alias, but don't forget the specify version to make it works as mentioned here
https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7093#issuecomment-814003563
else this will not work @GACy20

Comment: @DevTheJo The comment below the one you linked states otherwise... they say it works if 1) you specify the version and 2) you use Helm v2 "style" dependencies (i.e.using a separate requirements file). Maybe this is because they are using `condition` It's completely unclear exactly which combo is required to make this work...

Answer (score 1):

Actually it cannot be achieved in Helm (by aliases too) because values resolving doesn't work for aliased charts. The only way is to define values for chart name:

```
<chart_name not alias>:
  var1: value
  var2: value
```

The source issue: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7093

Comment: this will work with alias, but don't forget the specify version to make it works as mentioned here
https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7093#issuecomment-814003563
else this will not work